# Pinnacle TV tuner card, readreg error, dvb_register failed, cx8802 probe failed, firmware never loads

Tags: kernel, firmware

I'm trying to make this card work in a touch screen kiosk running Ubuntu 10.04, kernel 2.6.32-45-generic

This card seems to use the s5h1411 chip instead of the s5h1409 the modules are expecting. I've patched the cx88-dvb module as per this [thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-281161.html), but this doesn't seem to have made a difference.

The errors I've noted in dmesg are:

```
tveeprom 5-0050: Huh, no eeprom present (err=-6)?
```

and

```
s5h1411_readreg: readreg error (ret == -6)
cx88[0]/2: frontend initialization failed
cx88[0]/2: dvb_register failed (err = -22)
cx88[0]/2: cx8802 probe failed, err = -22
```

I also notice there's no mention of the firmware ever loading, nor is xc5000 even listed in lsmod.

I've saved some logs to a folder in [my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/79njakvx58k5800/eUElx6ousU/logs) for reference. I have dmesg, kern.log, lsmod, lspci -vvnn, and syslog. I also set debug=1 to xc5000, s5h1411, cx88-dvb, cx88xx, cx8802, and cx88_alsa, just in case there's some relevant information coming out.

Anybody have any insight to this problem?

Comment: Many times minor version changes in a card mean radical changes inside. Even more so for chipsets. Get complete details from `lspci(1)` or some such, and go from there.

Comment: I've included the output of lspci in the logs saved to Dropbox, which I've linked to. I haven't any idea where to go from here, most of what's provided in the output doesn't seem to mean anything to me just yet.